# Using .htaccess to redirect all pages on wordpress to homepages except page with .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how to Using .htaccess to redirect all pages on wordpress to homepages except page with extention .html

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so share your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you had a wordpress install, but not anymore, and want to redirect all urls that would previously link to a blog in wordpress to the site root. If that's the case, remove the rule that would rewrite the url to wordpress' index.php and add the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com [R,L]
```